# Apache Cocoon JAR configuration - I want to use .class files !

Tags: java, frameworks, jakarta-ee, jar, apache-cocoon

I'm using the Apache Cocoon framework, set up several eons ago for the web app I'm developing.

I don't know if its how cocoon is set up for everyone, or its if some 'special' configuration my company has performed, but this is what happens.

In order for cocoon to use ANY class files, they must be bundled up into a JAR and put in the tomcat(5) / common / lib directory. cocoon simply won't see the class files if we put them somewhere else.

Even if that somewhere else is in WEB-INF/classes or java or whatever.

Does anyone know how this configuration is set within cocoon (I'm a cocoon novice)? I want to be able to just bang my .class files in WEB-INF and away we go.

I know I should be using an IDE, but if you saw the app structure you would understand that I'm not. We're working towards it...

Many thanks in advance...

Mieze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Cocoon, but if you can put jars in tomcat/common/lib, then classes should work in tomcat/common/classes (NOT WEB-INF/classes).

Placing stuff into tomcat/common (instead of inside the webapp itself) is kind of weird, but you probably need to change some Cocoon settings (or the place where Cocoon is installed) to avoid that. Is Cocoon part of the webapp or also "tomcat common"?